# How to create a model scope with Geocoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models, User, Dad, Mom, Follow and Kid.

```
class User
 has_many :kids
 has_many :follows
 geocoded_by :address
end

class Dad
 has_many :kids
 has_many :follows
end

class Mom
 has_many :kids
 geocoded_by :address
end

class Follow
 belongs_to :dad
end

class Kid
 belongs_to :mom
 belongs_to :dad
 belongs_to :user
end
```

With the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem I'm trying to create a scope that takes in the total count of the Dad's Kids nearest to the User's location compared to the Kids Mom's locations that happened today.

```
<% @follows.each do |f| %>
 <% f.dad.kids.today.nearest.count
<% end %>
```

In my **ApplicationController**:

```
def set_user_location
  if signed_in?
   @user_location = current_user.address
  end
end
```

In my `Kid` model:

```
scope :today, -> { where("kids.created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day) }
scope :nearest, -> { joins(:mom).merge(Mom.near(@user_location, 2000)) }
```

But the `nearest` doesn't work. It doesn't load `Moms` at all.

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by FollowsController#index as HTML
  Follow Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 5]]
  Follow Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "follows".* FROM "follows" INNER JOIN "dads" ON "dads"."id" = "follows"."dad_id" WHERE "follows"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0  [["user_id", 5]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "dads".* FROM "dads" WHERE "dads"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "dads"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 39]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "kids" WHERE "kids"."dad_id" = $1 AND (kids.created_at > '2014-05-08 04:00:00.000000')  [["dad_id", 39]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "kids" WHERE "kids"."dad_id" = $1 AND (kids.created_at > '2014-05-08 04:00:00.000000')  [["dad_id", 39]]
```

What would be the correct way to write the `nearest` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `today` scope, not `nearest`.
Every model has sreated_at field so in your scope you should write

```
scope :today, -> { where("kids.created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day) }
```

EDIT:
Another error is that you're referring to controller instance variable in model. Model and controller are separated so it will not work this way. Instead you should rewrite scope to

```
scope :nearest, ->(location, distance=2000) { joins(:mom).merge(Mom.near(location, distance)) }
```

and then in the controller you may write

```
Kid.nearest(some location goes here)
```

but I think your models are a little messed up and you want them to do something different.
WhatI suppose you want to do is find a mother that is nearest to kid, so rather you should do something like

```
Mom.near(some_kid, 2000)
```

Comment: Even though that error is gone. Now I don't get any error but the `nearest` scope still isn't working.

Comment: The `nearest` scope isn't doing what I need it to do. Take a look at my query at the bottom, its not loading Moms.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. In your scope you're referring to `@user_location` but it's variable defined in controller so there's no way to use it like that in model.  See edited answer